# Real Time Depth Estimation in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I want to estimate depth from live video stream with two calibrated webcams in MATLAB but has no results. I have Webcam Support Package and Image Acquisition Toolbox but I don't know how to use live video stream via stereo calibrated webcams against recorded video file. In [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/depth-estimation-from-stereo-video.html) depth is estimated with two recorded video files.

How can I estimate depth in live video stream?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are having trouble with?  Were you able to calibrate your cameras? Is your problem only with adapting the example you cited to work with live video?

Comment: @Dima: With recorded video everything was OK but when I want to apply the process on  live video stream (real time) I couldn't do that. In this post (http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-live-video-acquisition.html) the problem for a single camera has been solved. However I couldn't adapt the solution for a stereo vision system (especially for depth estimation ).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to connect both cameras to your computer, and either create two `webcam` objects or two `videoinput` objects to read images from them.